# How does one get the original keybinding for Coq?

Tags: coq, coqide

I changed the key binding according to:

https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/Configuration-of-CoqIDE

but now I can't get them back to normal. How do I them to default state?

Note that Coq already changed the file and i can't figure out how to undo the changes I did.

---

just in case that webpage dies here are the instructions I followed:

Configuring the alternative set of bindings
(0) You need CoqIDE to have been executed at least once for the configuration file to exist.

(1) Before you make any change to these files, you MUST close all running instances of CoqIDE.

(2) You need find out the location of the configuration files coqiderc and coqide.keys:

On Linux, in ~/.config/coq/
On Windows, either in %HOME%.config\coq or in C:\Program Files\Coq\config
On Mac OS X, in ~/Library/Application\ Support/coq/
(3) Edit the file coqiderc and make the following change:

|before | modifier_for_navigation = "" | |after | modifier_for_navigation = "" |

(4) Edit the file coqide.keys and insert the following lines at the bottom of the file:

(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Go to" "F5")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Backward" "F6")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Forward" "F7")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/End" "F8")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Start" "F9")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Interrupt" "F12")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Previous" "")
(gtk_accel_path "/Navigation/Next" "")
(5) Open CoqIDE and test whether the new bindings work. They should appear in the Navigation menu.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you want to do, but if you want to reset to the default shortcuts, I guess just deleting the two files (`coqide.keys` and `coqiderc`) will make CoqIDE recreates them with the default values.

Comment: ok weird! It did create a new set of files (they were NOT the same as the ones I had when I installed coq from scratch, however, they new key bindings are MUCH better than what I had after just installing it. Something weird and subtle is going on. Probably not worth my time to get in the details...

Comment: so I guess your answer does restart the files to *something*, though unclear if its actually the original or what the word "original" should mean in this context.

Comment: Depending on your platform, there can be a few subtleties indeed. This was recently discussed [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/8567).